# Is there a difference in the initialisation of these two arrays?

Tags: c++, initialization

I wasn't the first first example to compile because for some reason I has in my head that the initialisation values needed to be compile-time known, but that obviously isn't the case. When are these values initialised? It's when call stack is set up, right? Is there a difference between the first example and the second one in actually how the arrays are initialised?

```
void getSomething(int block_size)
{
   int offsets[] = {
        0,
        block_size * 3       
    };
}

void getSomething2()
{
    int offsets[] = {
         0,
         1 * 3
    };
}
```

Both are these arrays are initialised when the stack is set up, right? In the first case there's a multiply because it doesn't know the value, but in the second argument there isn't, but the initialisation process of the array itself is the same, right?

Furthermore, if I add static to these arrays, I'm pretty sure that in the second case (where all the array values are known at compile-time), the array is initialised at the start of the program, whereas in the first case where the initialisation value can't be known then the program keeps a flag that it checks each time calling the function, to check if it's been initialised, and if it hasn't it initialises it?

Comment: The size of the array needs to be known at compile-time, but the initialization can happen at run-time. If all elements in the array are known at compile-time, or can be computed by the compiler at compile-time (simple constant expressions like `1 * 3` can be computed this way through *constant folding*), then the compiler might opt to create some memory with the values already initialized.

Comment: If you have a local `static` array, it will be initialized on the first call, and never again. So if `offsets` were `static` in the first function (`getSomething`) then if you call it like `getSomething(5)` the value `15` will be stored in the array. If you later call the function like `getSomething(10)` the value will *still* be `15`, because it won't be initialized again.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "If you later call the function like getSomething(10) the value will still be 15, because it won't be initialized again. " Oh boy, another gotcha, glad I learned that one.

Comment: @Zebrafish -- it's not a "gotcha"; it's fundamental to what `static` means on a local variable.

Comment: @PeteBecker Am I right in believing that if the initialisation can be compile-time evaluated then it's initialised at program start? And that it doesn't check a flag to test if it's initialised every function call?

Comment: @Zebrafish — function-static objects are constructed the first time the function is called (slightly oversimplified). On subsequent calls it’s already been constructed, so it shouldn’t be constructed again. And if the function is never called the object doesn’t get constructed, so it can’t be destroyed. So, yes, the code has to keep track of whether it’s been constructed.

Comment: @PeteBecker And the conditional check of whether it's been initialised already can be obviated if the initialisation can be compile-time evaluated and initialised as program start?

Comment: @Zebrafish — again: the object gets constructed the first time the function is called; if the function doesn’t get called the object doesn’t get constructed.

Comment: @PeteBecker I actually think the compiler makes distinction and treats it differently. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122603/c-initialization-static-variable-in-local-scope"

Comment: @Zebrafish -- under the "as if" rule, if the difference can't be detected by a conforming program, the compiler can rearrange things. That's why I've been careful to talk about **construction"", to imply that there's significant work being done. Constructing a function-static object with a constructor that has side effects before that function is called is detectable, so not allowed. Regardless: your mental model should be that function-static objects are initialized the first time the function is called.